html/css column centering and spacing
Brand new to web development like very brand new. I'm Creating a SharePoint site for my work using the Modern Script Editor web part. It will be a basically just a resource page with linked buttons on it. I am really havening trouble centering the three columns and evening the space between the columns. As I write more text into the buttons they come right up on each other. Any advice would be appreciated. Also I will need to make a a quick link column on the right side of the page, should I do anything different with it for the HTML side? I know the look will be different for the quick links so I'll figure out the css part. Fiddle
CSS
<style>
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
}

header {
    text-align: center;
}

.banner {
    color: #fff; /* Example text color */
}

.banner h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 0;
}

.sub-banner{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 37%;
    margin-right: 33%;
    font-size: 40px;
    flex: nowrap;
    background-color:black;
    color: white;
    border: solid 3px gold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
}    

.logos {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    
}

.logos a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logos a h3 {
    background: black;
    border: solid 3px gold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;        
        
}

.logos a:nth-child(2) {
 color:black;
}

.logos a img {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 175px;
}

main {
    text-align: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#h3s {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 200px;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin:;
}

#h4s {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 200px;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin:;
}

#h5s {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 200px;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin:;
}

</style>


HTML
<body>
  <header>
    <div>
      <button class="sub-banner">
        Resources
      </button>

    </div>

  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="logos">
      <div id="h3s">
        <a href="">
          <h3>Linked Button sogdfgij fkdjg dfpgj ddfpigj</h3>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <h3>Linked Buttons idjf sgij sdipgj </h3>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <h3>Linked Button sogj dfoigj doifgj </h3>
        </a>

      </div>
      <div class="logos">
        <div id="h4s">
          <a href="">
            <h3>Linked Button dofijgodfigj doij </h3>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            <h3>Linked Button pdofg pdofkg pofd kg</h3>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            <h3>Linked Button dpfgj dpiogj dpiogdj p od </h3>
          </a>

        </div>
        <div class="logos">
          <div id="h5s">
            <a href="">
              <h3>Linked Button</h3>
            </a>
            <a href="">
              <h3>Linked Button</h3>
            </a>
            <a href="">
              <h3>Linked Button</h3>
            </a>
           </div>
        </div>
  </main>

tried 33% margins for each column and a lot of stuff to much to remember.

I think you're over-complicating things:

gap allows you to specify a gap between flex items
flex-wrap allows items to spill over multiple rows
You also should validate your code, as headers should not be placed within a tags, and you can usually style elements without so much html.  Try and use tags semantically.

CSS
.logos {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 20px;
}

.logos a {
  flex: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  min-width: 25%;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

HTML
 <div class="logos">

        <a href="">
          Linked Button sogdfgij fkdjg dfpgj ddfpigj
        </a>
        <a href="">
          Linked Buttons idjf sgij sdipgj 
       
        <a href="">
          Linked Button sogj dfoigj doifgj 
        </a>


          <a href="">
            Linked Button dofijgodfigj doij </h3>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            Linked Button pdofg pdofkg pofd kg</h3>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            Linked Button dpfgj dpiogj dpiogdj p od 
          </a>

  
            <a href="">
              Linked Button
            </a>
            <a href="">
              Linked Button
            </a>
            <a href="">
             Linked Button
            </a>
           </div>
        </div>

fiddle
